# Escape reserved keyword in text t-sql

Tags: t-sql, keyword

I have an update statement erroring out:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[PRODUCTS]
SET APPLICATION = 'Nissan Diesel Applications with SD22 & SD25 Engines'
```

The problem is it doesn't like the "with" word. I have tried square brackets, back ticks, and double quotes. All of these prevent the error but then they are also stored in the data. How do I properly escape reserved keywords in quotes? Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any keyword problem here (though I also thought to check for that).  Please include the exact error message in your question.

Comment: Your syntax looks fine. Perhaps you can create a variable and assign its value as 'Nissan Diesel Applications with SD22 & SD25 Engines'. Then use the variable in your update.

Comment: Is this statement followed by a common table expression (CTE)? (From [`WITH` common_table_expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#guidelines-for-creating-and-using-common-table-expressions): "When a CTE is used in a statement that is part of a batch, the statement before it must be followed by a semicolon.")

Answer (score 0):

Here is the error message I received:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

I also discovered the actual issue was a non-escaped ' on the previous line. Thanks for the help guys!